# Update text-box in Microsoft Word with VBA

Tags: vb.net, ms-word, textbox

I am having issues updating a textbox using VBA OnClick. I have the properties of the textbox set as follows:

```
Name: ContentController_CN
Tag: CC_CN
Modifiers: Friend
LockContentControl: False
LockContents: False
PlaceHolder Text: Click here to enter text.
```

The block of code I am trying to use to update the field is as follows:

```
    Private Sub Btn_Calculate_Click(sender As Object, e As RibbonControlEventArgs) Handles Btn_Calculate.Click
    Dim todaysdate As String = String.Format("{0:dd/MM/yyyy}", DateTime.Now)
    Dim doc As Document = Globals.ThisDocument.Application.ActiveDocument
    Dim range As Range = doc.Range
    Dim custName As String = TB_CustName.Text
    Dim shp As Shape
    Dim str As String

    For Each shp In doc.Shapes
        str = "My name is " & shp.Name("ContentController_CN")
        str = str & vbNewLine & "My EditID is " & shp.EditID
        shp.TextFrame.TextRange.Text = str
    Next
End Sub
```

The goal of this application is to have the user enter text in an UI Ribbon then when they click a button text fields in the document are updated with their input.

I have been endlessly reviewing the TextFrame object information on MSDN and have not been able to accomplish this. Could someone please revise the above code to pull from TB_CustName? I originally had some code that looked like this:

```
        doc.Shapes("ContentController_CN").TextFrame.TextRange.Text = TB_CustName.Text
```

When running this line of code I get the following error:

```
System.ArgumentException was unhandled by user code
  HResult=-2147024809
  Message=The index into the specified collection is out of bounds.
  Source=""
  StackTrace:
       at Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Shapes.get_Item(Object& Index)
       at azul.gem_ui.Btn_Calculate_Click(Object sender, RibbonControlEventArgs e) in C:\Users\DMI\Desktop\Neo\BlueGem\proj\azul\azul\gem_ui.vb:line 20
       at Microsoft.Office.Tools.Ribbon.RibbonPropertyStorage.ControlActionRaise(IRibbonControl control)
       at Microsoft.Office.Tools.Ribbon.RibbonPropertyStorage.ButtonClickCallback(RibbonComponentImpl component, Object[] args)
       at Microsoft.Office.Tools.Ribbon.RibbonManagerImpl.Invoke(RibbonComponentCallback callback, Object[] args)
       at Microsoft.Office.Tools.Ribbon.RibbonManagerImpl.System.Reflection.IReflect.InvokeMember(String name, BindingFlags invokeAttr, Binder binder, Object target, Object[] args, ParameterModifier[] modifiers, CultureInfo culture, String[] namedParameters)
  InnerException:
```

**Any help is greatly appreciated. Thank you all for your insight. :)**

Comment: what kind of "textbox" is that .. is it something that you added in the Visual studio Designer or from the Word Developer tab? Is it in the `doc.Range.ContentControls` collection?

Comment: It is a textbox created through the developer tab.

Also, it is not within the ContentControl collect.

Comment: If it is ActiveX control, check if it is in the `Document.InlineShapes` collection `doc.InlineShapes(1).OLEFormat.Object.Text = "test"` or I am not sure if you can access it directly like in VBA `doc.ContentController_CN.Text = "test"`

Comment: When I tried doc.ContentController_CN.Text = custName I got a runtime error:

System.MissingMemberException

Comment: This does not seem like VBA at all, rather VB.NET with VSTO.